# Overlay in Views not Working

Tags: views

I am using Views 7.3.8 with Drupal 7.30. I use this combination for a total of 5 individual sites.

On 1 of my sites when I go into any view>>> edit page and try to click on field/title or any link on the edit page, the overlay pops up with a blank screen and just sits there empty.

I have tried disabling along with several other things short of uninstall/reinstall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error usually causes due to **Jquery version incompatibility**, try installing [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and navigate to

`example.com/admin/config/development/jquery_update`

and choose jQuery version for administrative pages as **1.5 or 1.7**